# Insert into one database from another database?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, scheduledexecutorservice

I am working with Postgres sql database.. I need to run a SQL query against `database-A` and whatever results I am getting from that query, I need to insert the results into `database-B` as it is and this has to be done every weekly on Friday.

So I decided to use `ScheduledExecutorService` which will call a particular method every week on Friday which does the above job.

Below is my method `(getFromDatabase)` which will run every Friday -

In the below method, I am executing a simple select query against `database-A` and I am storing the result in `TestResponse` method

```
protected static void getFromDatabase() {
    TestResponse response = null;
    TestDaoImpl dao = new TestDaoImpl();
    String sql1 = "select col1, col2 from application limit 5";
    try {
        // get the data from database-A table
        response = dao.getFromDatabaseA(sql1);
        System.out.println(response);

        // now iterate this response and then insert into database-B table
        insertIntoDatabase(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void insertIntoDatabase(TestResponse resp) {
    // how to use resp so that I can generate below correct insert SQL query?
    // which I can use to execute it?

    String query = "INSERT into table-database-B .... ";
}
```

And below is my `getFromDatabaseA`  method -

```
private List<String> col1List = new LinkedList<String>();
private List<String> col2List = new LinkedList<String>();

 public TestResponse getFromDatabaseA(String query) throws Exception {
    TestResponse response = new TopMalwareAppsResponse();
    try {
        conn = TestConnection.getInstance().getCpds().getConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        // Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
        // Retrieve by column name
        String col1 = rs.getString("col1");
        col1List.add(col1);

        String col2 = rs.getString("col2");
        col2List.add(col2);
       }

        response.setCol1(col1List);
        response.setCol2(col2List);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
    }
```

Below is my `TestResponse` class in which all the values of `col1` will go to `col1` linked list and all the values of `col2` will go to `col2` linked list.

```
public class TestResponse {

    private List<String> col1;
    private List<String> col2;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now I am not sure how to iterate `TestResponse` in `insertIntoDatabase` method in such a way so that I am able to make proper SQL query. And then I can use thi SQL query as it is to insert.

Comment: uou should use SELECT * FROM old_table INTO new_table

Comment: @ChiragSutariya: Really? Is this possible? How would I do that? Can you provide me an example, how will this work for my current SQL?

Comment: yes it is possible below i write two syntax in answer

Comment: rate up my answer if you got idea

Comment: Have a look at the dblink module or the Postgres FDW (foreign data wrapper). Both extensions enable you to run queries across different databases (even servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserted list of column details in to an object it is not a good behaviour,

change it as

```
    public class TestResponse {

  private String col1;
  private String col2;

 // getters and setters
  }
```

use like

```
     List<TestResponse> responses = null;
```

Use

```
    private static void insertIntoDatabase(List<TestResponse> resps) {
// how to use resp so that I can generate below correct insert SQL query?
// which I can use to execute it?
**// Iterate the above list and update second table**
String query = "INSERT into table-database-B .... ";
```

}

alter

```
    getFromDatabaseA
```

like this

```
     List<TestResponse> testResponses = new ArrayList<TestResponse>();

     // Iterate for values or execute query for multiple time to get all details from table 1
   {  
     TestResponse testResponse = new TestResponse();
     testResponse.setsetCol1(/*  ADD COL1 DATA */);
     testResponse.setsetCol2(/*  ADD COL2 DATA */);

     testResponses.add(testResponse);
     }
     return testResponses;
```

Comment: The how would my `getFromDatabaseA` method will look like? Can you show me an example of that as well if possible?

Comment: You only wrote this dao.getFromDatabaseA(sql1); means please change the return object @akiiddweeber it made your job easy.

Comment: Thanks saran. But my `getFromDatabaseA` will change as well right? Or just the return type needs to change?

Comment: You need to change return object as List<TestResponse>,Create new TestResponse inside getFromDatabaseA add to a list. @akiiddweeber

Comment: @akiiddweeber alter getFromDatabaseA like i mentioned above